# Server Snapshot Capture For Cloning

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chef

I have a situation and would love to hear your suggestions.

Situation:

1. I have a server that is hosting several important workflow applications on cloud.
2. Changes are made to few add-ons apps on the server like httpd.conf files.

What I like to do:

1. Be able to capture the present state configuration of server with application settings etc.. completely and store the captured config and state information in a smart file  that I can use
   to launch another server quickly that is a photo copy of the one I captured.

   This is somewhat similar to what Chef achieves I believe, where it captures the installation and launch configs.

Whats the best way to achieve this.

Comment: Chef does not capture the current state, you have to define the desired state and can then apply it multiple times (and let the configuration evolve). But blueprint can be used as a starting point for that.

Comment: I think you might be looking for [Docker](https://www.docker.com/whatisdocker/).

Answer (score 1):

Look into **Blueprint** - http://devstructure.com/blueprint/#create

This will help you accomplish what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

For the record I think the best solutions I got is creating custom Amazon Machine Image and registering it with AWS. I can then use it to request spot instance or launch a new instance in a heartbeat and it is an exact replica of the creating instance at the time of AMI formation.